# Вызов функции из native-библотеки

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Есть вот такая функция в *C++* нативной библиотеке:

```
void __stdcall someFunction(__in const char *arg, __out char *arg2, __in const char *arg3);
```

пытаюсь ее вызвать в *C#* программе:

```
    [DllImport("Somelib.DLL", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void someFunction(String input, ref String text, String key);

    .........

    String text = "";
    someFunction("someText1", ref text, "someText2");
```

и получаю исключение **System.AccessViolationException**.

Как правильно вызывать такой метод? Что я здесь делаю неправильно?

Comment: Попробуйте объявить второй аргумент как `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Без разницы, все равно выпадает в System.AccessViolationException.

Comment: Все, разобрался - убрал ключевое слово **ref**  и все заработало.

Answer (score 3):

На общем [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241087/4535033) есть такой совет:

> Strings are a bit difficult in P/Invoke. My general rule of thumb is:
>
> - Input char* parameter = c# string
> - Return char * = IntPtr (use PtrToStringAnsi)
> - Output char* parameter = c# StringBuilder - and be sure to pre-allocate it large enough before (ie = new StringBuilder(size))
>     calling the function.

Что по-русски:

- В качестве входного параметра char* = string
- В качестве возвращаемого значения char* = IntPtr (use PtrToStringAnsi)
- В out параметре char* = StringBuilder, но необходимо заранее инициализировать переменную нужного размера.

Т.е. в качестве параметра нужно передавать переменную инициализированную через new StringBuilder(size), где size - достаточный размер для возвращаемого значения.

**UPDATED:**

Вообще, StringBuilder по умолчанию передаётся по ссылке, т.е. вообще не нужно добавлять модификаторы.

Comment: Я попробовал задать большой размер для  StringBuilder передаваемом во втором аргументе, это не помогает, та же ошибка. В c++, в нативном c++, я без проблем вызываю эту функцию вот так: 

`typedef void (__stdcall *MYPROC)(const char *arg,char *arg2,const char *arg3); `

Comment: А есть message из получаемого исключения?

Comment: _"Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена."_

Больше ничего,StackTrace только путь до моей функции.

Comment: А почему в объявлении функции указано ref, а не out? Вообще, StringBuilder по умолчанию передаётся по ссылке, т.е. вообще не нужно добавлять модификаторы.

Comment: Обновил ответ для указания причины ошибки.